# Why std::pair calls explicit constructors in assignment

Tags: c++, constructor, standards-compliance, explicit

Consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>


struct Base
{
    int baseint;
};

struct Der1 : Base
{
    int der1int;
    Der1() : der1int(1) {}
    explicit Der1(const Base& a) : Base(a), der1int(1)
    {
        std::cerr << "cc1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Der2 : Base
{
    int der2int;
    Der2() : der2int(2) {}
    explicit Der2(const Base& a) : Base(a), der2int(2)
    {
        std::cerr << "cc2" << std::endl;
    }
};


template <typename T, typename U>
struct MyPair
{
    T first;
    U second;
};

int main()
{
    Der1 d1;
    Der2 d2;

    std::pair<Der1, int> p1;
    std::pair<Der2, int> p2;

    p1 = p2; // This compiles successfully

    MyPair<Der1, int> mp1;
    MyPair<Der2, int> mp2;

    mp1 = mp2; // This will raise compiler error, as expected.
}
```

Tested under GCC 4.5.2

The reason lies in `std::pair` sources:

```
  /** There is also a templated copy ctor for the @c pair class itself.  */
  template<class _U1, class _U2>
    pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
    : first(__p.first),
      second(__p.second) { }
```

Is that behaviour compliant with the C++ standard? For a first sight it looks inconsistent and counterintuitive. Do the other implementations of STL work the same way?

Comment: Why exactly do you think this is inconsistent and counter-intuitive? What are you objecting to? I think it’s perfectly expected behaviour.

Comment: You're not showing the std::pair assignment operator. That's the one that is relevant.

Comment: std::pair assignment operator is not defined or I'm blind.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph - I didn't expect that explicit constructor will be called when I do an assignment.

Comment: @Steve: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the emphasis on `explicit` -- I'm removing my comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand the question, but basically you are asking why two unrelated `std::pair` can be implicitly convertible even if the instantiating types are not implicitly convertible. That is, why the *implicitly* convertible property of the instantiating types does not propagate to the pair.

The standard does not provide explicit assignment operators for the `std::pair` template, which means that it will use the implicitly generated assignment operator. To be able to assign pairs of convertible types, it relies on a templated constructor that allows an *implicit* conversion from `std::pair<A,B>` to `std::pair<C,D>`, the behavior of which is defined in §20.2.2 [lib.pairs]/4

```
template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V> &p);
```

> Effects: Initializes members from the corresponding members of the argument, performing implicit con-
>   versions as needed.

The standard seems to only require the implementation to use *implicit* conversions, and in this particular implementation the conversion is actually explicit, which seems to contradict the wording of the standard.

Comment: How would you actually implement that, though? Putting `__p.first` in the initializer list, calls explicit constructors. But if you don't do that, `this->first` needs to be default-constructible, which also doesn't conform. Does `std::pair` need magic compiler internals to avoid explicit conversion, or am I missing the trick?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I was thinking about that and it does not seem easy to do. I guess that the solution would template metaprogramming to detect whether the type is implicitly convertible and an static assert if it isn't. That should be easy enough to implement, but will add some complexity to the implementation. Now that I think of it, this will probably break explicit conversions from `std::pair<A,B>` to `std::pair<C,D>` so this might not be a solution either

Comment: That's a very good question. Unfortunately, I do not know any STL implementation which behaves correctly.

Comment: @rawicki: I don't think that it can actually be done. I have [implemented](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/i-decided-to-start-writing-few-months.html) the SFINAE approach (and took the opportunity to start yet another blog --shame on me for self promotion here) and because it is a constructor (no return type) the failure has to be triggered with an extra constructor parameter, and that breaks standard compliance.

Answer (score 2):

As part of class std::pair the constructor

```
template<class T1, T2>
class pair
{
public:

    template<class _U1, class _U2>
    pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
         : first(__p.first),
           second(__p.second)
    { } 

};
```

is not a copy constructor, but a converting constructor from any `pair<_U1, _U2>` to `pair<T1, T2>`. This works for cases where the `first` and `second` members are convertible to the corresponding member of the other pair.

Converting each member separately is according to the standard.

Comment: *Converting each member separately is according to the standard*: yes, but the standard adds *implicit* to that sentence, and in this case the implementation is doing *explicit* conversions, which is the reason for the question itself.

Comment: @David How would you write this constructor?

Comment: @David - Ok, I might have focused on the part of this not being an assignment or a copy constructor and missed the `explicit` part of the question. C++0x says that this constructor should not be considered if the members are are not implicitly convertible, but the C++98 standard does not say so, and provides no tools to decide it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment, but I prefer some room to type this out.

So, lets say we have two types:

```
typedef std::pair<A,B> pairAB;
typedef std::pair<S,T> pairST;
```

Now I want to assign one to the other:

```
pairAB x;
pairST w;

x = w; // how?
```

Since `std::pair` doesn't have an explicit assigment operator, we can only use the default assignment `pairAB & operator=(const pairAB &)`. Thus we invoke the *implicit* conversion constructor, which is equivalent to:

```
x = pairAB(w);  // this happens when we say "x = w;"
```

However, has has been pointed out, this conversion constructor calls the *explicit* member constructors:

```
pairAB(const pairST & other) : first(other.first), second(other.second) { }
```

Thus for each member individually we do use explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Because the standard says it should.

Your next question, of course, will be: Why does the standard say so?

Imagine this line, which I think you agree should work:

```
std::pair<long, long> x = std::make_pair(3, 5);
```

But as `3` and `5` are ints, we are trying to assign a `std::pair<int, int>` to a `std::pair<long, long>`. Without a templated constructor and a templated assignment operator, it would fail, as your `MyPair` proved.

So to answer your question: the templated constructor is for convenience. Everyone expects to be able to assign an int to a long. So it is reasonable to be able to assign e.g. a pair of ints to a pair of longs.

Comment: I don't think that the standard mandates this. See my answer. The only quote I could produce is from 20.2.2 and it requires that a `std::pair<A,B>` is implicitly convertible to `std::pair<C,D>` *performing **implicit** conversions as needed*. What the implementation is actually doing is performing an **explicit** conversion.

Comment: But `int` is implicitly convertible to `long`. `Der2` is explicitly but *not* implicitly convertible to `Der1`. I think it would make sense that if `X` is not implicitly convertible to `Y`, then `pair<X,X>` should not be implicitly convertible to `pair<Y,Y>`. This implementation just doesn't achieve that (I can't immediately think how it would).

Comment: `Der2` is implicitly convertible to `Base`. And there is a `Der1` constructor taking a `Base`. One implicit and one user-defined conversion is allowed when converting types, so the conversion from `Der2` to `Der1` is allowed. As there is an explicit initialization (how would it be possible without?), the `explicit` does not prohibit this conversion.

Comment: So what does the word "implicit" signify in 20.2.2, if not that explicit conversions are excluded? Does it perhaps mean that the conversion from `U` to `T1` can be explicit, but *additional* implicit conversions are performed as needed?